# sendredirect not working as expected. No exception thrown

Tags: java, httpresponse, http-redirect

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void logout(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    eraseCookie(request, response);

    response.sendRedirect("/index.html");

}
```

Html button :

```
<span class="submitButton"><button class='btn btn-primary pull-right'
                                           onclick="returnHomepage()">Logout</button></span>
```

JS:

```
function returnHomepage() {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: "/logout",
                dataType: "json",
                crossDomain: true,
                async: false
            }).responseText;
}
```

Its not redirecting me to the home page "index.html", when I click logout it does hit the controller, I have kept the debugger at controller and its hitting it, it even passes sendredirect method, but does nothing.

even tried `response.sendRedirect("index.html");`

I have even tried returning after sendredirect, but it does nothing.
Need help.

Comment: It's because you are making a xmlhttprequest. Remove the `$.ajax` and make the request using a form, it will then redirect.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Yes it worked, I changed the button to form. 

`<form class="form-logout" role="form" action="/logout">
                <input type="submit" value="Logout" id="logout" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
            </form>`